# Prove or disprove that two holomorphic functions are equal.

Tags: complex-analysis

This is the text of the exercise:
Let $f,g$ be holomorphic functions on $D=|z|<2$ such that:
(i) $f(0)$ and $g(0)$ are positive real numbers
(ii) $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ don't vanish in $|z|\leq1$
(iii) $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ for every $|z|=1$
Prove or disprove that $f=g$ on $D$.

My idea was to use the $log(f)$ and $log(g)$ on the simply connected domain $|z|<1+\epsilon$ (for some $\epsilon$ small enought) to say that $f$ and $g$ are the same except for a rotation and by (i) conclude that the rotation must be the identity.
I think it doesen't work (if it can helps i can put the details).
Is there another approach to solve this exercise?

Comment: *Hint:* What can you say about $h=f/g$?

Comment: This hint i s not enought for me i think.. can you please add were to go?

Comment: I've tried to use $log(\frac{f}{g})$ but seems not work..

Comment: Apply a basic theorem of Complex Analysis  to $\frac f g$ and $\frac g  f$.

Comment: Ok so the maximum principle implies that $h$ is constant.. I feel very stupid, but thanks